# onclick password alert while there is onclick print as well

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem where i have a button for print button i want to prompt/alert a password before the print window pops out

this is my jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/95ezN/884/

```
document.getElementById("btnPrint").onclick = function () {
printElement(document.getElementById("printThis"));
 }

function printElement(elem) {
var domClone = elem.cloneNode(true);

var $printSection = document.getElementById("printSection");

if (!$printSection) {
    var $printSection = document.createElement("div");
    $printSection.id = "printSection";
    document.body.appendChild($printSection);
}

$printSection.innerHTML = "";
$printSection.appendChild(domClone);
window.print();
}
```

i am able to open a prompt but i want input type password then i want the print window to open

Please help

Comment: You can not have `type='password'` in prompt. Use `absolute` positioned pop-up to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your script like this:

```
document.getElementById("btnPrint").onclick = function () {
var password;

    var pass1="cool";

password=prompt('Please enter your password to view this page!',' ');

if (password==pass1)
{ 
  printElement(document.getElementById("printThis"));
} //Close if here
} // Close your btnPrint click function here

function printElement(elem) {
var domClone = elem.cloneNode(true);

var $printSection = document.getElementById("printSection");

if (!$printSection) {
    var $printSection = document.createElement("div");
    $printSection.id = "printSection";
    document.body.appendChild($printSection);
}

$printSection.innerHTML = "";
$printSection.appendChild(domClone);
window.print();
}
```

Here is the updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/95ezN/887/)

Comment: brO the print window is NOT coming

Comment: It is coming here. Check this screenshot http://snag.gy/gCXk4.jpg. I have checked in Firefox/Chrome/IE 11. Its working (if you put password as 'cool')

Comment: after entering pass1 print window is not coming

Comment: yes that would not come. As `pass1` is the variable, but its value is 'cool'. So when you enter 'cool' as your password, then it comes

Comment: if i want input type password like want to hide the password what should i do

Comment: That cannot be achieved with prompt. The popup is browser controlled and can't be changed. Check this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp) for better understanding. But you can always use other kind of jquery alerts for the same like alertify.js and there are many more

Comment: is its giving me this when i put the code in my file and truy execute it   the prompt is coming but the print window is not                               Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cloneNode' of null Please help

Comment: Check if `elem` is null or not

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cloneNode' of null  i tries to console.log(elem) but its not happeining

Comment: its showing error on this line of javascript   var domClone = elem.cloneNode(true);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101371/discussion-between-alorika-and-taha-dhailey).

Answer (score 0):

There is logical error.

Explain:

```
/* $printSection is declared */
var $printSection = document.getElementById("printSection");
/* if $printSection isnt exists.. */
if (!$printSection) {
    /* ERROR : make new local variable that named as $printSection*/
    var $printSection = document.createElement("div");
    $printSection.id = "printSection";
    document.body.appendChild($printSection);
}
/* this code is the same as null.appendChild(domClone) */
$printSection.appendChild(domClone);
```

So this code should be like

```
var $printSection = document.getElementById("printSection");
if (!$printSection) {
    /* like this*/
    $printSection = document.createElement("div");
    $printSection.id = "printSection";
    document.body.appendChild($printSection);
}
$printSection.appendChild(domClone);
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/95ezN/889/)**